# How can I connect one to many relationship in laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel

Image model:

```
public function getImage(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
}
```

Product model:

```
public function product(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
}
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
     $products = Product::all(); //Select *
     return view('product.index',compact('products'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
     <td>{{ $product->getImage->image_link}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Error:

> Trying to get property 'image_link' of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ecommerce\resources\views\product\index.blade.php)

Comment: You need to add some dummy data in your database currently you're trying to bring an empty data.

Comment: you need to define getImage relationship in your Product model not in image model and that will be hasMany relationship

Comment: you reversed the methods. `getImage()` should be in the product model and `product()` in the image model. anyway, $product->getImage will return collection so try $product->getImage[0]->image_link

Comment: Solved!!! I'm just missing that first index in getImage[0]. Thanks pal and N69S.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a `product_id` field in your image table? and is there `hasMany` in your `Product` model?

In your `Product` model should be a relation like as below.

**Product.php**

```
public function images(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
}
```

After then, you can use images in product for loop `$product->images->image_link`.

Answer (score 0):

Their should be a relation between post and product with product id

In Product.php

```
public function product(){
return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
```

}

then you can use  `$product->images->image_link`